# Differential equation book with lots of exercises

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am a post-doc with a PhD in theoretical physics. I have a background in the theory of differential equations, but I feel i lack of technique, so I am looking for a differential equations (ODE and PDE) book with lots of exercises.

Can anyone suggest any?

Comment: This is not an answer, but seems to me to suggest the answer(s): https://dl.icdst.org/pdfs/files3/6fbc8b85b3086b0c53d70c82cd0626d1.pdf

Comment: Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Kreyszig has a lot of exercises for both ODEs and PDEs, though this may be under your level. Also, Mathematical Methods for Physicists by Weber has a fair few exercises on a more expansive range of topics than Kreyszig.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am sorry but it seems that I cannot access to that link for security reasons I get error 1020

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/34138116/Handbook_of_Differential_Equations_3rd_edition